# Como pegar o nome da rede que o dispositivo está conectado

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou querendo fazer um sistema php que será acessível também via celular mas para poder logar no sistema ele deverá validar se está dentro de determinada rede, caso não esteja não poderá fazer o login. Sendo mais específico quero que ele pegue o nome (SSID) da rede Wi-Fi em que o celular esta conectado para depois comparar com a rede que é permitido. É possível fazer isso? Se for, poderiam mostrar como fazer ou mandar links que mostrem como fazer.

Comment: Até onde sei somente com código nativo, pois você precisaria de permissões do dispositivo para isso. Uma forma (eu mesmo já fiz isso) seria trabalhar com roteadores wi-fi que tenham a função de captive portal, como Ubiquiti e TP-Link.

Answer (score -3):

Talvez você consiga alguma informação que lhe auxilie com essa documentação: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php.

Como o php roda do lado do servidor, você teria que acessa-las para mostrar essa informação.

Temos as variáveis `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` que armazena o IP real do cliente.

Deixo também um link do stackoverflow onde fala sobre algo relacionado, onde você poderia criar uma função pra controlar o acesso através do IP, tem bastante informação e funções para fazer o que precisa.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php